# haml and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

i have a show.html.haml file that calls a display.js
in my controller I have a variable @category

how would I use @category in my display.js file that's being used by view?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe some code examples would help, I think what you're trying to do is Display.initialize(@category.to_json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess I just needed to take a short break; here:

```
= javascript_tag do
    var category = '#{@category}'

= javascript_include_tag "your_javascripts.js"
```